# Breakdown of HTML RTF string for 3rd Party Formatting

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have decided to come here with my problem as my head is fried and I have a deadline. My basic scenario is that on our system we save RTF HTML in the database, for example:

```
This is<strong> Line 1</strong> with more <strong>Bold and <em>italic</em></strong> text
```

Which renders as following:

This is **Line 1** with more **Bold and *italic*** text

These HTML strings are exported to PDF and up until now the PDF renderer used could read and render this HTML correctly... Not any more. I am therefore having to do this the manual way and read each tag individually and apply the styling on the fly as I construct each paragraph. Fine.

My idea is to build a list of strings, for example:

```
"This is "
"<strong>Line 1</strong>"
" with more "
"<strong>Bold and <em>italic</em></strong>"
" text"
```

Each row either has an un-formatted string or contains all style tags for a given string.

I should then be able to build up my paragraph one string at a time, checking for tags and applying them when required.

I am however mentally failing at the first hurdle (Friday afternoon syndrome??) and cannot figure out how to build my list. I'm guessing I am going to use RegEx.

If someone is able to advise on how I might be able to get a list like this would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

Following a Python example suggested below I have implemented the following, but this only gives me the elements surrounded by tags and none of the unformatted text:

```
        var stringElements = Regex.Matches(paragraphString, @"(<(.*?)>.*?</\2>)", RegexOptions.Compiled)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Value)
            .ToList();
```

So close...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found a solution by using the glorious Html Agility Pack:

```
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(paragraphString);

        var htmlBody = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"/p");
        HtmlNodeCollection childNodes = htmlBody.ChildNodes;
        List<string> elements = new List<string>();

        foreach (var node in childNodes)
        {
            elements.Add(node.OuterHtml);
        }
```

As a note, I was previously removing the Paragraph tags surrounding the html from the paragraphString but have left them in for this example. So the string being passed in is actually:

```
<p>This is<strong> Line 1</strong> with more <strong>Bold and <em>italic</em></strong> text</p>
```

I think the RegEx answer has some credibility and I am sure there is something in there that is just excluding the non 'noded' elements. This seems nicer though as you have access to the elements in a class-structure kinda way.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize up front, since my answer is written in Python, however I hope this provides you with some guidance.

```
import re

s = 'This is<strong> Line 1</strong> with more <strong>Bold and <em>italic</em></strong> text'

matches = [i[0] for i in re.findall(r'(<(.*?)>.*?</\2>)', s)]

for i in matches:
    s = s.replace(i, '\n' + i + '\n')

print(s)
```

Gives:

```
This is
<strong> Line 1</strong>
 with more 
<strong>Bold and <em>italic</em></strong>
 text
```

Comment: Thanks for that Rahlf... I will give it a proper look later. I am guessing the  re.findall is a Regular Expression? I wonder if it directly transfers to C#... I shall find out and let you know.

Comment: You bet. And yes, re.findall is a method in the regular expression (regex) library of Python.

Comment: The Regex compiles fine and seems to half do the job in C#... I only seem to be getting the 2 x strings that start with <strong> and I do not get any of the un-formatted strings. Close! I will see if I can play with this but RegEx is not my strong hand! Thanks again Rahlf23

Comment: I might add I didnt quite know exactly what is going on in the For Loop so wonder if that has anything to do with the difference between what we are seeing?

Comment: The line with the for loop is actually a list comprehension, very useful in Python!